# Django settings don't load on other views.py

Tags: python, django

manager.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=9992 daemonize=false

then, when i start nginx as webserver, i get an error.

settings.py

```
from lib import rpc
rpc.backend = ARPCClient({xxxxxx})
```

asite/views.py

```
from lib import rpc

AttributeError at /
    'rpc' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you don't have the import statement for the settings

```
from settings import *
```

or substitute * with rpc.backend if you need only that.

Comment: well, the error is pretty clear, are you sure you have the atribute "backend" for the rpc object? did you follow a guide to setup this? also "from lib import rpc" are you sure it's correct? what does lib refer to?

Comment: actually the lib.rpc.backend is initialize in settings, then, i use it in view. lib refer from a folder that in the django project site folder.